# Escape the top level of a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, implode

Hi I can't seem to find an answer anywhere to this question I have. I know its something simple.

Lets say you have a two dimensional array it looks something like this:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => dairy
                        [terms] => cheese
                        [field] => slug
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => dairy
                        [terms] => yogurt
                        [field] => slug
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => brand
                        [terms] => independent
                        [field] => slug
                    )

            )
```

how do I break it down into a single dimensional array like so

```
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => dairy
                        [terms] => cheese
                        [field] => slug
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => dairy
                        [terms] => yogurt
                        [field] => slug
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => brand
                        [terms] => independent
                        [field] => slug
                    )"
```

The reason I ask this because I wish to make dynamic query, that needs to be formatted as such. Normally I would just foreach the original array and cycle though it and generate the needed information, but the information is part of larger array. Which means I cannot use a foreach loop from inside the larger array.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could escape the parent array reach such formatting?

Comment: You can use `serialize($var);` where $var can be any array and object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I do not think you are looking for a recursive implode.

I think the function better suited for your needs is [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

```
<?php
$string = var_export($array, true);
```

Comment: Yes this is the correct function I needed.Thank you I am one step closer.

I did the following before passing it to my query:
`foreach($args as $arg){
     $string .= var_export($arg, true) .',';
 }`

My only issue is when I try to use $string as is, it appears as warped in a single keyed array, however if I echo it, or dump it, it behaves as a string. Know why?

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. Try to this after your `foreach` loop: `$string = strval($string);` Does that solve anything?

Comment: After testing I am wrong. Your answer is correct to what I asked. My question is poorly worded.